# Getting graph lengths from image junctions with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, graph, junction

This question is built off of this other question. Assuming I have a stable junction algorithm implemented. I am trying to derive a graph from the junctions.

I am stuck on:
How do I move along a line in openCV and calculate the path length?

So for example when evaluating point C:

C connects with:

- The junction A and has a path length of 20 pixels
- The junction D and has a path length of 112 pixels
- The junction F and has a path length of 30 pixels
- The endpoint E and has a path length of 45 pixels

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you know the locations of the junctions and you're just counting the pixels (unweighted graph), then breadth-first search would work.

Comment: @beaker Maybe the "C connects with: ..." section is misleading. I do not have this information I need to derive it. In its current state I do not have the graph in order to do a breadth-first search i.e. I dont know that junction A is connected with Junction B I just know they exist. I will need to be able to follow the path in order to determine that Junction A is connected to Junction B. Once I can follow a path and count the pixels I can determine then that A is connected to B to later build my graph. I guess my question is more of how to follow the path and calculate the path length.

Comment: Do you have the locations of the junctions? Given a location in the image, you should be able to determine which of its neighboring pixels are 0 and 1 (or 255 or whatever). If nothing else, you could make each 1 pixel in the image a node in an adjacency matrix, but really all you need is to create a `neighbors` function to return which of the adjacent pixels are reachable.

Comment: @beaker Yes I do do have the location of the junctions. I will give the neighbors approach a try and see what I can come up with. Thanks.